# Unity Facebook SDK IOS Not Returning to app

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to use Facebook login with an iOS app built in Unity. I'm using the Facebook Unity SDK (7.9.0). The login seems to work fine, but afterwards, instead of returning to the app, I stay in the safari window, with a blank white screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBb6t.png)

I saw some similar questions on StackOverflow, but none were answered in enough detail for me to work out what to do to fix it, and I don't have enough reputation to ask clarifying questions :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I never found out what caused this problem, but I uninstalled the Facebook SDK and then reinstalled it and it works as expected now. I suspect that I didn't copy the code across from their examples exactly correct or something.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this question when searching on Google like I did. I was running iOS 10.3 with Unity 5.6 and had this happen. The specific reason I found was that Firebase Invites was not compatible with the Unity Facebook sdk. Once I removed it everything worked as expected so make sure to check your other third party libraries.

Answer (score -1):

TLDR : Place these [2 files](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/etliaojing/aanKj) into Plugins/iOS folder and that fixes it.

What version of Unity are you using?
This seems to be a Unity 5.5 bug, see [this conversation](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/900542723380664/) on Facebook Developer forum